# String to Number returns wrong result in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why converting the String "948226952292454401" to a Number fails with 
all JS methods like Number, parseInt, Math.floor, etc.?

It always returns 948226952292454400.

```js
var string = "948226952292454401"
console.log(Number(string))
console.log(parseInt(string))
console.log(parseFloat(string)) 
console.log(Math.floor(string))
console.log(Math.ceil(string))
console.log(+string)
```

Comment: `948226952292454401 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER //true`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: JS recently added [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) which may also be helpful here.

Comment: Shouldn't it return NaN then?

Comment: @rx2347 it is not a "not a number" value. It's most definitely a number. It's just imprecise.

Comment: Thx guys, I'll close this as duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

Max value largest possible positive numbers that JavaScript can work with.